# text.matches command not found in core addon

Tags: g1ant

I tried to use text.matches command in G1ANT but it gives the error that text.matches command not found.

```
text.matches ‴Name: John Surname: Smith‴ regexes \wn.mE
dialog ♥result
```

Answer (score 1):

G1ANT removed the `text.matches` command from G1ANT.Addon.Core because it was unnecessary and the same thing can be done using the [text.find](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Commands/TextFindCommand.md) command.

For example:

```
text.find text ‴Name: John Surname: Smith‴ regex ‴\wn.mE‴
dialog ♥result
```